# How can I redirect the output of a child process?

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

I am running the following `git clone` command through `sudo` and `bash` and I want to redirect STDOUT to a log file:

```
% sudo -u test_user bash -c "git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
/home/test_user/.vim/bundle/nerdtree >> /var/log/build_scripts.log"
```

What is happening is the STDOUT is continuing to be sent to the terminal. i.e.

```
Cloning into 'nerdtree'...
remote: Counting objects: 3689, done.
[...]
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the fact that `sudo` is forking a new process then `bash` is forking another, as demonstrated here:

```
% sudo -u test_user bash -c "{ git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
/home/test_user/.vim/bundle/nerdtree >> /var/log/build_scripts.log; ps f -g$$; }"  

  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 6556 pts/25   Ss     0:02 /usr/bin/zsh
 3005 pts/25   S+     0:00  \_ sudo -u test_user bash -c { git clone https://github.com/scrooloo
 3006 pts/25   S+     0:00      \_ bash -c { git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.
 3009 pts/25   R+     0:00          \_ ps f -g6556
```

I've tried

- running this in a script and using `exec >> /var/log/build_script.log` before the command
- wrapping the command in a function, then calling and redirecting the functions output

But I think these redirections are only applying to the parent and  the child processes are defaulting to sending STDOUT to the `/dev/tty/25` of their parent causing output to continue to the terminal.
How can I redirect the STDOUT of this command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The messages you mention are not printed to standard output but to standard error. So, to capture them, you either need to redirect standard error instead of standard output:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "git clone https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo 2>> log"
```

Or both STDERR and STDOUT:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "git clone https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo >> log 2>&1"
```

With `bash`, you can also use `&>>` for this:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "git clone https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo &>> log"
```

The `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh` equivalent being `>>&` (`(t)csh` don't support `2>&1` so it's the only way there):

```
sudo -u user csh -c "git clone https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo >>& log"
```

In `fish`

```
sudo -u user fish -c "git clone https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo >> log ^&1"
```

For more on the different types of redirection operators, see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/22222)

Now, in the specific case of `git`, there's another issue. Like a few other programs, `git` can detect that its output is being redirected and stops printing progress reports if so. This is probably because the reports are intended to be seen live and include `\r` which can be a problem when saved in a file. To get around this, use:

```
       --progress
       Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default
       when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is specified. This
       flag forces progress status even if the standard error stream is
       not directed to a terminal.
```

And:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "git clone --progress https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo >> log 2>&1"
```

If you want to both see the output as it comes *and* save to a file, use `tee`:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "git clone --progress https://github.com/foo.git ~/foo 2>&1 | 
    tee -a log
```

Comment: thanks, I'm testing now, I need to append so I'm using `2>>&1` but bash is returning `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token &'`

Comment: When I run the command from @skwllsp answer, i.e. using `&>>` most of the output is lost. If `git clone` was sending to STDERR I would have thought these messages would have continued to the terminal when using `&>>` but they seem to disappear?

Comment: @the_velour_fog you can't use `2>>&1`. Just use `sudo .. git ... >> log 2>&1` that appends. However, it looks like `git` detects that its output is being redirected and stops printing the progress report. You can see the same behavior if you just run `git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git 2>err` directly. The progress reports are no longer printed. I haven't been able to figure out a way to trick `git` into printing even when redirecting.

Comment: yes im discovering this weird behaviour of git clone just now. to restore the output use the --progress option as defined in the man page. apparently git clone will quite itself when piped etc.

Comment: @the_velour_fog yes, many programs behave differently when their output is being piped. For example, `grep` has the `--color=auto` option won't print color if it is being redirected. This is usually a good thing.

Comment: yes grep --auto turns off the color character sequences intended for a terminal but git clones "put everything through stderr" loses the ability to selectively redirect output . the only solution I can think of is to send everything to the terminal and just live with the noisy output so I don't miss error messages

Comment: @the_velour_fog no, you can save it to a file with the `--progress` option, See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
/home/test_user/.vim/bundle/nerdtree &>> /var/log/build_scripts.log
```

Comment: thanks, this is partially working, its sending the first line to log_file but then remaining output it lost - I think @terdon may have explained whats happening, testing now...